# How to match two data frames by column values within sub-blocks of the data frame?

Tags: r, merge, subset

I have two data frames that I would like to match based on values in a column (column ‘gridcell’) present in both data frames. This would be an easy task, if not for the fact that this needs to be done separately for each unique date in the data frames.

Below is some example data:

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(index = 1:7, date = c("13/04/2011", "13/04/2011", 
"04/04/2011", "04/04/2011", "04/04/2011", "28/03/2011", "28/03/2011"
), yrday = c(103L, 103L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 87L, 87L), gridcell = c(6L, 
9L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 4L), dist = c(178L, 158L, 137L, 116L, 95L, 
135L, 115L), ang = c(148, 147.6, 163.6, 159.7, 152.5, 152.2, 
121.9)), .Names = c("index", "date", "yrday", "gridcell", "dist", 
"ang"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

> dput(df2)
structure(list(date = c("28/03/2011", "28/03/2011", "28/03/2011", 
"28/03/2011", "28/03/2011", "28/03/2011", "28/03/2011", "28/03/2011", 
"28/03/2011", "29/03/2011", "29/03/2011", "29/03/2011", "29/03/2011", 
"29/03/2011", "29/03/2011", "29/03/2011", "29/03/2011", "29/03/2011", 
"04/04/2011", "04/04/2011", "04/04/2011", "04/04/2011", "04/04/2011", 
"04/04/2011", "04/04/2011", "04/04/2011", "04/04/2011", "13/04/2011", 
"13/04/2011", "13/04/2011", "13/04/2011", "13/04/2011", "13/04/2011", 
"13/04/2011", "13/04/2011", "13/04/2011"), yrday = c(87L, 87L, 
87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 
88L, 88L, 88L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 103L, 
103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L), gridcell = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L), r = c(161L, 162L, 162L, 164L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 
170L, 170L, 171L, 170L, 169L, 168L, 158L, 160L, 162L, 164L, 165L, 
263L, 258L, 255L, 250L, 246L, 242L, 239L, 238L, 228L, 235L, 234L, 
231L, 230L, 229L, 228L, 227L, 243L, 242L)), .Names = c("date", 
"yrday", "gridcell", "r"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-36L))

> head(df1)
  index       date yrday gridcell dist   ang
1     1 13/04/2011   103        6  178 148.0
2     2 13/04/2011   103        9  158 147.6
3     3 04/04/2011    94        2  137 163.6
4     4 04/04/2011    94        5  116 159.7
5     5 04/04/2011    94        8   95 152.5

> head(df2)
        date yrday gridcell   r
1 28/03/2011    87        1 161
2 28/03/2011    87        2 162
3 28/03/2011    87        3 162
4 28/03/2011    87        4 164
5 28/03/2011    87        5 167
```

I would like to end up with a new df1 data frame that includes the matching row from df2, based on identical 'gridcell' values within each date (as below):

```
  index     date_1 yrday_1 gridcell_1 dist   ang yrday_2 gridcell_2   r
1     1 13/04/2011     103          6  178 148.0     103          6 228
2     2 13/04/2011     103          9  158 147.6     103          9 242
3     3 04/04/2011      94          2  137 163.6      94          2 258
4     4 04/04/2011      94          5  116 159.7      94          5 246
5     5 04/04/2011      94          8   95 152.5      94          8 238
6     6 28/03/2011      87          3  135 152.2      87          3 162
7     7 28/03/2011      87          4  115 121.9      87          4 164
```

So far, I have tried merging the two data frames by the ‘date’ column, which gives a new data frame in which every row from df1 is repeated by the number of rows for the matching date in df2 (i.e. every possible ‘gridcell’ value from df2 is matched to the unique df1 row).

```
df1$date = as.Date(df1$date, format="%d/%m/%Y")
df2$date = as.Date(df2$date, format="%d/%m/%Y")
nw.df = merge(df1,df2, by="date")
```

I am sure that the ‘index’ column, which has unique values, can then be used within a function such as `ddply` to condense the new data frame, leaving only rows with matching ‘gridcell’ column values for each unique  ‘index’ value (i.e `ddply(nw.df, .(index, …), summarise, …)`
). I just can’t figure out how to do this! Any suggestions/help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to merge on both date and gridcell: `merge(df1, df2, by = c("date", "gridcell"))`?

Comment: @ Henrik: Haha! So simple. I did not realise that merge() could be used for more than one variable. Many thanks! (you can have the accepted answer if you wish?)

Comment: OK! I posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify both 'date' and 'gridcell' as columns used for merging:

```
merge(df1, df2, by = c("date", "gridcell"))
```

The drawback with this code is that the 'yr.day' column is duplicated. Thus, you may wish to subset 'df2' to only include the columns used for merging, together with the column(s) you wish to add (here 'r'):

```
merge(x = df1, y = df2[ , c("date", "gridcell", "r")])

#         date gridcell index yrday dist   ang   r
# 1 04/04/2011        2     3    94  137 163.6 258
# 2 04/04/2011        5     4    94  116 159.7 246
# 3 04/04/2011        8     5    94   95 152.5 238
# 4 13/04/2011        6     1   103  178 148.0 228
# 5 13/04/2011        9     2   103  158 147.6 242
# 6 28/03/2011        3     6    87  135 152.2 162
# 7 28/03/2011        4     7    87  115 121.9 164
```

Note that we don't need to specify `by` columns here. If `by` is not given, `merge` finds the columns used for merging by `by = intersect(names(x), names(y))` (see `?merge`), here: `intersect(names(df1), names(df2[ , c("date", "gridcell", "r")]))`

However, if you wish to be explicit (which sometimes is useful...), this will give the same result:

```
merge(x = df1, y = df2[ , c("date", "gridcell", "r")], by = c("date", "gridcell"))
```